UnknownHostException when trying to connect Spring to Postgres in fly.io
I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot application with a PostgreSQL database on Fly.io, but I keep encountering the UnknownHostException: db-app.flycast error. Here's the process I've followed:

I used the Fly CLI to create the PostgreSQL database named db-app:
flyctl postgres create -n db-app --autostart true --region cdg --vm-size shared-cpu-1x --initial-cluster-size 1 --volume-size 2


Next, I created a Spring Boot application named example-app on Fly.io:
flyctl apps create example-app -o org


I attached the PostgreSQL database db-app to the Spring Boot application:
flyctl attach db-app -a example-app --database-name db --database-user user


then I deployed it using a configuration file fly.toml:
flyctl deploy --config fly.toml -a example-app -ha=false --volume-initial-size 2

fly.toml configuration:
kill_signal = "SIGINT"
kill_timeout = 5
swap_size_mb = 1024

[build]
  dockerfile = "../docker/Dockerfile.app"

[http_service]
  internal_port = 8080
  force_https = true
  auto_stop_machines = true
  auto_start_machines = true
  min_machines_running = 0
  processes = ['app']



I consistently receive the following error:
java.net.UnknownHostException: db-app.flycast

I have:

Confirmed that the PostgreSQL database db-app is created successfully on Fly.io.

Verified DNS resolution for db-app.flycast using ping and nslookup, ensuring it resolves to the correct IP address.

Ensured that both the Spring Boot application and PostgreSQL database (db-app) are within the same Fly.io organization and region, and reviewed network policies.

Verified that application.properties or application.yml in the Spring Boot application correctly points to db-app.flycast with the appropriate port and credentials.

Checked Fly.io logs (flyctl logs -a example-app) for any connectivity issues or errors related to database access.


How can I resolve the UnknownHostException issue and ensuring successful deployment of my Spring Boot application with PostgreSQL on Fly.io?
